# Aggregation with $and not working in rmongodb

Tags: aggregation, rmongodb

I have a very simple stage in an aggregation pipe that causes me trouble. The following works as expected in the shell:

```
db.People.aggregate(
{$match: {$and: [ {"Name": "B^M"}, 
                  {"ID": "0006221671"} ] } } 
)
```

However, I tried to run the same with rmongodb and get back error(10):

```
query <- '{"$match": {"$and": [ {"Name": "B^M"}, 
                                {"ID": "0006221671"} ] }}'    

cmd <- list(mongo.bson.from.JSON(query))

mongo.aggregation(db, collection, cmd))
```

Can anybody give me a hint why this does not work? Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

please check this rmongodb issue for more details: https://github.com/mongosoup/rmongodb/issues/17

Answer (score 0):

Try to construct bson from list as described in [github thread](https://github.com/mongosoup/rmongodb/issues/17#issuecomment-57428852). In latest version it should work fine. You can install it directly from gihub:

```
library(devtools)
install_github('mongosoup/rmongodb')
```